# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Base64$Encoder on Centos 7

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

**Summary**

We have spring boot projects that working on Tomcat in Centos 7. I'm using kafka for message transactions. When tomcat started, @KafkaListener 's trying to get metadata. At that time I'm getting exception;

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Base64$Encoder

**What I've Tried**

At the first place i thought this was all about old kafka-logs. I removed them and restarted the server. Everything was fine. But today i got this exception again. Removing kafka-logs didn't solve my issue.

- Kafka Broker Version: kafka_2.13-2.8.0
- Kafka Client Version: org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.8.0
- OpenJDK: 1.8.0_292

> SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type
> [org.apache.kafka.common.requests.MetadataRequest] Reported exception:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Base64$Encoder
> at org.apache.kafka.common.Uuid.toString(Uuid.java:101)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.message.MetadataRequestData$MetadataRequestTopic.toString(MetadataRequestData.java:662)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.MessageUtil.deepToString(MessageUtil.java:53)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.message.MetadataRequestData.toString(MetadataRequestData.java:373)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.toString(AbstractRequest.java:115)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.toString(AbstractRequest.java:120)
> at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.safeObjectAppend(MessageFormatter.java:277)
> at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.deeplyAppendParameter(MessageFormatter.java:249)
> at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:211)
> at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:161)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.writeLog(LogContext.java:428)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.debug(LogContext.java:229)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.doSend(NetworkClient.java:522)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.doSend(NetworkClient.java:501)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.sendInternalMetadataRequest(NetworkClient.java:467)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1141)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1046)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:559)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1296)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1206)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1110)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using Java 1.8 and not an older version?

Comment: [root@server/]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

And as far as i know tomcat gets default JAVA_HOME classpath. @Shawn